# stretching an image to fill a canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a PhotoImage that I am loading into my cavas using create_image(). I can anchor this image and move it around the canvas, but I can't seem to find a way to stretch it so it fills the canvas.

I can zoom() on the PhotoImage, but this takes an integer zoom coefficent, so if the canvas is much larger than the image I can't fill it exactly.

There must be a way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way. Tkinter can only scale images by integer factors. Your only solution is to use another library (such as [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)) to resize the image.